# Count of records of table in mssql server

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to fetch the no. of records/count from a mssql table but getting:

> pymssql.ColumnsWithoutNamesError: Specified as_dict=True and there are columns with no names: [0]

Here is what I am trying:

```
cur = hook.get_cursor()                        
cur.execute(self.sql)
```

And the query is:

```
select count(*) from abc
```

Comment: *hook* is your connection to the database? Did you already try the _mssql module of pymsqql?

Comment: yes **hook** is the connection to _db_.
I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pymssql/JoZpmNZFtxM):

> The problem is that if you open the connection or cursor with
>   as_dict=True, then every column in the output has to have a name. With
>   a regular database table column, the output name inherits from the
>   column name. If you have a SQL expression like calling a function on a
>   column name (e.g.: MAX(foo)), then the output column doesn't have a
>   name and so it doesn't get displayed. There are two things you can do
>   to make it work:
>
> ```
> 1. Give the SQL expression a name -- e.g.: SELECT MAX(foo) AS [MAX(foo)]...
> 2. Don't use as_dict=True for these queries
> ```

I think same for COUNT function. So try to give the result a name with "AS".

Or have a look for the *_mssql* module of *pymsql* (here is also an [example](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/_mssql_examples.html?highlight=count) for COUNT:

```
import _mssql
conn = _mssql.connect(server='SQL01', user='user', password='password', database='mydatabase')
numemployees = conn.execute_scalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees")
```